# How can I make a paragraph corners round?

Tags: c#, wpf, border, paragraph

I have a rich text box which I add paragraphs to (dynamiclly), 
I want to make the paragraphs borders round when I add them, how can I do that? 
This is the code that I have:

```
    <Grid>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="315" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="312" IsReadOnly="True" >
        <FlowDocument x:Name="flowDocument" >

        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

I tried accessing the paragraph border property, but I couldnt do it. 

 I have something like this in my code:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Run("Some text"));
p.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
p.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
//Make the paragraph border round
flowDoucment.Blocks.Add(p);
```

Any idea how could I set the border's `CornerRadius` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using the BlockUIContainer and again one more RichTextBox inside it. Refer below code.

```
<RichTextBox>
        <FlowDocument>  
            <BlockUIContainer>
                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue" CornerRadius="8" Padding="3"> 
                    <RichTextBox  BorderThickness="0">
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph>This is paragraph with border</Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox>                        
                </Border>
            </BlockUIContainer>    
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: I have another small qustion, by doing it your way it works very good, but the problem is that theres no speaces between paragraphs now, look at this image: http://prntscr.com/8vxw32
How can i insert speaces between the paragraphs?

Comment: I used your xmal code and used this code to generate 10 paragraphs:
`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                BlockUIContainer con = new BlockUIContainer();
                Border b = new Border();
                b.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0.5);
                b.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
                b.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5);
                b.Child = new RichTextBox(new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run(i.ToString()))));
                con.Child = b;
                MainFlowDoucment.Blocks.Add(con);
                
            }`

Comment: *i used your xmal just to run a few tests, ill probably modify it before i use it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following manner:

```
<Border Height="315" Width="312" BorderBrush="Bisque"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="20">
        <RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox"  Height="315"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderThickness="0"   Width="312" IsReadOnly="True" >

        </RichTextBox>
    </Border>
    <Border Height="315" Width="312" BorderBrush="Bisque"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="20" />
```

[image]

Comment: Still nothing, i just get a border around my rich text box and not around the paragrahps

Comment: for me it worked fine. See image. you need to specify verticallaignment and other properties  in broder tag

Comment: Yes but thats not what i wanted..
I wanted that the Paragraphs will have a border, not the rich text box
http://prntscr.com/8vvmhd